# Apex extracting fields from a trigger to create a custom JSON

Tags: apex, trigger, json, after-trigger, jsongenerator

I have created a trigger for Order Object and only want specific fields to be pulled from that object to create a custom JSON data structure. I have tried saving the fields that I need from the object into local variables, placing them into a list and then serializing them but the output is wrong. The curly brackets are missing and commas are not being added in the proper locations. Please reference my code below.

```
trigger ActiveOrder on Order (after insert, after update) {
    private String ordAccountId;
    private String ordBillingStreet;
    private String ordBillingCity;
    private String ordBillingState;
    private String ordBillingPostalCode;
    private String ordBillingCountry;
    private String ordDescription;
    private Double ordTotalAmount;
    private String ordOrderNumber;
    private String ordShipToContact;
    private String ordShipToMethod;
    private String ordShippingStreet;
    private String ordShippingCity;
    private String ordShippingState;
    private String ordShippingPostalCode;
    private String ordShippingCountry;
    private String ordBillToAttn;
    private String ordCustomerPO;
    private String ordShipToAttn;

    for(Order o : Trigger.New) {
        if(o.Status == 'Activated') {
            ordAccountId = o.AccountId;
            ordBillingStreet = o.BillingStreet;
            ordBillingCity = o.BillingCity;
            ordBillingState = o.BillingState;
            ordBillingPostalCode = o.BillingPostalCode;
            ordBillingCountry = o.BillingCountry;
            ordDescription = o.Description;
            ordTotalAmount = o.TotalAmount;
            ordOrderNumber = o.OrderNumber;
            ordShipToContact = o.Ship_To_Name__c;
            ordShippingStreet = o.ShippingStreet;
            ordShippingCity = o.ShippingCity;
            ordShippingState = o.ShippingState;
            ordShippingPostalCode = o.ShippingPostalCode;
            ordShippingCountry = o.ShippingCountry;
            ordBillToAttn = o.BillToAttn__c;
            ordCustomerPO = o.Customer_PO__c;
            ordShipToAttn = o.Ship_to_Attention__c;

            List<String> ordInvoice = new List<String>();
            ordInvoice.add('Account Id: ' + ordAccountId + ', ' 
                           + 'Billing Street: ' + ordBillingStreet + ', ' 
                           + 'Billing City: ' + ordBillingCity + ', ' 
                           + 'Billing State: ' + ordBillingState + ', ' 
                           + 'Billing Postal Code: ' + ordBillingPostalCode + ', ' 
                           + 'Billing Country: ' + ordBillingCountry + ', ' 
                           + 'Description: ' + ordDescription + ', ' 
                           + 'Total Amount: ' + ordTotalAmount + ', ' 
                           + 'Order Number: ' + ordOrderNumber + ', ' 
                           + 'Ship To Contact: ' + ordShipToContact + ', ' 
                           + 'Shippin Street: ' + ordShippingStreet + ', ' 
                           + 'Shipping City: ' + ordShippingCity + ', ' 
                           + 'Shipping State: ' + ordShippingState + ', ' 
                           + 'Shipping Postal Code: ' + ordShippingPostalCode + ', ' 
                           + 'Shipping Country: ' + ordShippingCountry + ', ' 
                           + 'Bill To Attn: ' + ordBillToAttn + ', ' 
                           + 'Customer PO: ' + ordCustomerPO + ', ' 
                           + 'Ship To Attn: ' + ordShipToAttn);

            System.debug('Pre JSON: ' + ordInvoice);

            String ordInvoiceJSON = JSON.serialize(ordInvoice);

            System.debug('Post JSON: ' + ordInvoice);
            System.debug('Post JSON: ' + ordInvoicePostJSON);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that something like this should work

```
trigger ActiveOrder on Order (after insert, after update) {
    public class JSONOrderInfo {
        private String ordAccountId;
        private String ordBillingStreet;
        ...

        public JSONOrderInfo(Order newOrder) {
            this.ordAccountId = newOrder.AccountId;
            this.ordBillingStreet = newOrder.BillingStreet;
            ...
        }
    }

    for(Order o : Trigger.New) {
        if(o.Status == 'Activated') {
          String ordInvoiceJSON = JSON.serialize(new JSONOrderInfo(o));
        }
    }
}
```

It's a similar solution to what's presented in Salesforce's JSON docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm).